# Why is my Intel Wireless 5100 card performing at half of its capacity?

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I always wonder about the broadband in my Intel WiFi Link 5100. I have a wireless network at home and the poor performance is confusing.

In windows 7 the adapter says it is at 350mbps with win drivers. In Ubuntu, connection information just say 150mbps. Same adapter, same N-Network. I'm using Intel's open source driver. I checked, and the intel module is active.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to edit this file:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/intel-5300-iwlagn-disable11n.conf
```

change this line:

```
 options iwlagn 11n_disable=1
```

to:

```
 options iwlagn 11n_disable=0
```

If you do not have that file there may be another cause.

Comment: Nope, I dont have this file :S.